# Error when copying a word to array character by character

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, error-handling

I'm trying to copy an unknown length of characters into an array, but I keep getting an error. I'm getting this from a website converted to text. Site is the position of the first character of the word (I want to copy 4 words), and result is the whole text file.

I keep getting this error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

for this line: `webget = result(sites(i)+n);`

```
for i = 0:3;  %for finding first 4
    webget = 'p'; %placeholder
    website = []; %blank
    while strcmp(webget,' ') == 0;
        for n = 0:150; %letter by letter, arbitrary search length
            webget = result(sites(i)+n);
            website = strcat(website,webget);
        end
    end
    website(i) = website;
end
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Hint: `for i = 0:3` sets `i` to `0`, which is not a positive integer. Now where is `i` being used?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab arrays index starting from 1, not 0.  On your first loop iteration, i=0, so your request for the 0th entry in the sites array is not valid.

Consider using i = 1:4.